# js - kcfinder tinymce implementation

Tags: javascript, html

How can you get the absolute image url from KCFinder?

KCFinder URL Link: http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/

Also tried this resource: http://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/kcfinder/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=23

Answer (score 0):

set on your config file (kcfinder)
from `'uploadURL' => "../../upload"`, => `'uploadURL' => "http://domain/upload"`
it's works for me